# Slow upload speed from Azure Function to a Container in a Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I'm experiencing a slower upload speed than I need to meet a project goals. We need to upload files up to 0.5GB from an AZ Function service to one of our storage accounts. This process is taking more time than we expect (>10min). Another issue that got our attention is the non-linearity of the relationship between file size and upload time. A 160MB file is taking 1.5min to upload but a 290MB exceeds 10min. Does anyone understand why this is happening? We didn't manage to figure it out through the community/docs.

My *function.json* file looks like this:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "az_func.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 0 0 * * 2"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "cvmdailyreports/test_func_json.csv",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsCVMDataStorageConn",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

The *az_func.py* script just scrapes some data from a website, manipulates some data and returns a csv (this process doesn't take too long, so it is not the source of inneficiency).

Anyone knows if it is normal for AZ functions to take that long to upload files to AZ Storage Accounts or if there is a faster way to do it?

The *az_func.py* code is the following:

```
import datetime
import logging

import azure.functions as func

from src.data.import_data import import_daily_reports
from src.data.transform_data import transform_daily_reports


def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest):
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)

    csv = transform_daily_reports(import_daily_reports(n=8)).to_csv(index=False)

    logging.info('The csv was created, sending to upload now.')

    return csv
```

The transform and import functions are custom functions to import some data from a website and to concatenate that into a dataframe. As stated before, they run without a problem, as can be seen in the logs from the App Insights:
[Invocation Details - Timeout Error Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fdfxc.png)

The Function App is running on linux, with runtime version 4.0

We are currently using the Consumption plan, which has the 10 mins limitation for timeout, and I already configured the *host.json* file to have the max timeout possible.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably wanna share the related code with us ?

Comment: Can you please share the code of the upload and also share the details of: app service, app service plan, storage account?

Comment: I have edited the post adding the az_func.py script and some more details on the Function App, hope it helps! I believe there is no need to share the code for the custom functions I created to import and transform data, as the log image I shared shows that the file is being created without errors, but if you guys think it is necessary let me know and I can upload it as well.